# jQuery Binding on the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got problem with jquery

page1.html

```
<div id="gold">gold value</div>
<!-- NAVIGATE -->
<a href="page2.html">Go to page 2</a>
```

page2.html

```
<div id="gold">gold value</div>
<!-- NAVIGATE -->
<a href="page1.html">Go to page 1</a>
```

main.js

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow',  function () {

   $('#gold').html(100);
});
```

This code working for page1.

When I navigate from page1 to page2 on page2 is string "gold value".

Its only working when I change main.js and page2.html like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow',  function () {

   $('#gold').html(100);
   $('#gold2').html(100);
});
```

and 
when I change in page2.html

```
div id="gold2"
```

Comment: Are you sure you have added main.js in page2.html?

Comment: Yes I added main.js to both pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the page loading method of jQuery Mobile, you may have many pages in the DOM at a certain time.

jQuery Mobile uses `div` elements with attribute `data-role="page"` to represent pages. First, make sure that your pages have a unique `id`, it does not matter if you separate your pages in many HTML files.

Now you can access your duplicate ID element specifying the current active page:

```
$(document).pagecontainer("getActivePage").find("#gold");
```

But I *really* recommend avoiding duplicate IDs, even in different pages. Use a `class` instead:

```
<div class="gold">gold value</div>
```

and

```
$(".gold").html(100);
```